# Проблема c чтением csv на windows. 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position (Python)

Tags: python, csv

возникла проблема с чтением csv на windows.

Мне нужно прочитать файл csv с русским текстом и статистикой

Работаю в pycharm. Ранее выполнял код на маке, и там проблем не было.
Перешел на Windows, и там выдается ошибка:
"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 119: invalid continuation byte"

Пробовал в настройках менять кодировку, указывать кодировку при чтении, но не помогло

В пути к файлу только английский язык

Код:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cashe.csv')
```

Содержимое файла:

"121548221 (2021-12-03 - 2022-03-02)"

Date    CampaignName    Criterion   Clicks  Cost    Conversions_157094482_LYDC

2021-12-03  [Поиск] ФГДС (Радиус 3км)   гастроскопия желудка    1   13.04   --

2021-12-03  [Поиск] ФГДС (Радиус 3км)   фгдс    6   287.66  --

2021-12-03  Ретаргетинг [РСЯ] поп.страницы  Квартирная помощь 14 дней   1   15.26   --

2021-12-03  [Поиск] ГЕО. Услуги (Парнас)    клиники +на парнасе спб 1   23.51   --

2021-12-03  [Поиск] ГЕО. Услуги (Парнас)    мед клиника парнас  1   94.00   --

Comment: «указывать кодировку при чтении» — как указывали и какую?

Comment: Скорее всего тут поможет `df = pd.read_csv('cashe.csv', encoding='cp1251')`, но по правильному нужно открыть этот `cashe.csv` например в `FAR` и найти ему правильную кодировку. Эту кодировку и указать потом при чтении файла в `Pandas`.

Comment: Попробуйте с кодировкой `utf-8-sig` что соответствует кодировке `utf-8 with BOM`